# tableView beginUpdates and tableView endUpdates does't work on iOS 5 Device

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5

I am working on UITableView. My application works fine with iOS 4 devices, but when I install the same app on an iOS 5 device, the UITableView method [tableView beginUpdates] and [tableView endUpdates] does not perform the required task.

Any ideas of what the problem is?

Comment: When i click 1st row in iOS 4 Device the 2nd row goes down and make space for info view. but when i am trying same process on iOS 5, the new view comes over the 2nd row. Any Idea?

Comment: can you post the code, just tested this on a ios5 device and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things I'm seeing in your code, you are not actually inserting/deleting any new row in your UITableView and the beginAnimations block is only used for that purpose. From the [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> beginUpdates Begin a series of method calls that insert, delete, or
>   select rows and sections of the receiver.
>
> - (void)beginUpdates Discussion Call this method if you want subsequent insertions, deletion, and selection operations (for
>     example, cellForRowAtIndexPath: and indexPathsForVisibleRows) to be
>     animated simultaneously. This group of methods must conclude with an
>     invocation of endUpdates. These method pairs can be nested. If you do
>     not make the insertion, deletion, and selection calls inside this
>     block, table attributes such as row count might become invalid. You
>     should not call reloadData within the group; if you call this method
>     within the group, you will need to perform any animations yourself.

The second things that I'm seeing is that you are also using animation blocks that are now [discouraged in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html):

> Animating Views
>   Use of the methods in this section is discouraged in iOS 4 and later. Use the block-based animation methods instead.

What I would try is to move to the new code with a conditional statement, depending on the iOS version where your app is running.

Comment: Thanks for reply. what i am doing is.. select any row, increase the height of selected row and putting a new view in selected row... the code for dynamic cell height is -                  (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 float height;
 
 if(indexPath == [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]) 
 {
  height = 90.0;
        }
 if (indexPath != [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow])
 {
  height = 45.0;
 }
 return height; 
} same code is working fine on iOS 4 device. but not working on iOS 5.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure if you should be using the beginUpdates block, though it probably shouldn't matter, the most important thing in your code are the animations, in the new iOS 5 the documentation recommends you to use the new animations methods instead of the old animation blocks. Also, you could try calling [myTableView reloadData]; Either that or try hiding your cell and then showing it again using the updates blocks you already have in your code. Hopefully I'm helping.